# Determine HTML Element's dimension

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to get an element's dimensions without all 'space consuming' CSS options.
Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    #foo {
        height: 48px;
        margin: 64px;
        width: 120px;
        padding: 23px;
        border:  7px solid red;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">

<input type="text" id="foo"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Computed style looks like this:

[image]

What I tried:

1.) clientHeight and clientWidth

```
document.querySelector('#foo').clientHeight
94
document.querySelector('#foo').clientWidth
166
```

2.) getClientRects and getBoundingClientRect

```
document.querySelector('#foo').getClientRects() // identical to getBoundingClientRect()
DOMRectList {0: DOMRect, length: 1}
0: DOMRect {x: 72, y: 72, width: 180, height: 108, top: 72, …}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: DOMRectList
```

3.) width and height:

```
document.querySelector('#foo').width
0
document.querySelector('#foo').height
0
document.querySelector('#foo').style.height
""
document.querySelector('#foo').style.width
""
```

Expected output:

```
{'width: 120, height: 48}
{'element': {'width: 120, height: 48}, 'spacing': {'top': 64+7+23, 'left': 64+7+23 ...}  // perfect!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being, I ended up in going through the attributes of `window.getComputedStyle(el, null)` to identify which attributes are relevant.

```
let spacingAttrs = [
  'borderBottomWidth', 
  'borderTopWidth', 
  'borderRightWidth',
  'borderLeftWidth',
  /*
  'marginBottom',
  'marginLeft',
  'marginRight',
  'marginTop',
  */
  'paddingBottom',
  'paddingLeft',
  'paddingRight',
  'paddingTop',
]

let num = 0
let el = document.querySelector('#foo')
let rect = el.getClientRects()[0];
let style = window.getComputedStyle(el, null)
let numberPattern = new RegExp(/\d+/);
let spacing = {'left': 0, 'right': 0, 'top': 0, 'bottom': 0}

for (let attr of spacingAttrs) {
  if (attr in style) {
    num = 0;
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(spacing)) {
      if (attr.toLowerCase().includes(key)) {
        num = numberPattern.exec(style[attr]);
        if (num) {
          // assuming units are Pixels only!
          spacing[key] += parseInt(num)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

result = {
  'rect': {
    'w': rect.width - spacing.left - spacing.right,
    'h': rect.height - spacing.top - spacing.bottom
  },
  'spacing': spacing
}
```

Out:

```
rect: {w: 120, h: 48}
spacing: {left: 30, right: 30, top: 30, bottom: 30}
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this code helping you

```
var foo = document.querySelector('#foo')
window.getComputedStyle(foo).margin; 
window.getComputedStyle(foo).width; 
window.getComputedStyle(foo).padding; 
window.getComputedStyle(foo).borderBlockEndWidth;`
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('#foo').offsetWidth` returns `180`.

Comment: you can use window.getComputedStyle() function...

ex:

window.getComputedStyle(foo).margin;

window.getComputedStyle(foo).width;

window.getComputedStyle(foo).padding;

window.getComputedStyle(foo).borderBlockEndWidth;